# Hi im coding in Laravel and i would like to access my $request variables in it

Tags: php, laravel

Hi everyone  i made a form that looks like in pHP laravel and the request result came out like this. I would just like to access it class_id=+8&class_status=1&class_id=+9&class_status=1 ( i did echo $request;)

the form code looks like this

{{ Form::open(array('url' => route('userEditOnboardingClassStatus'), 'class' => 'ui form'))}}
         @foreach($userOnboardingClasses as $onboardingClass)
      course_id }}">
                                
                                {{$onboardingClass->course_title}}
                                    {{$onboardingClass->course_description}} 
                                
                                    @if($onboardingClass->status==1)
         
                      status}}> Incomplete
                            Completed

```
       </select>
                                @endif
                            </td>


                            </tr>
                            @endforeach

                        </tbody>

                    </table>

                    <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-med editCustomerModalBtn" style="float:right">
                        <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap"></i> Submit
                    </button>
                    {{Form::close()}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access to all request properties with
`$request->all()`

You can access to a specific props with
`$request->get(props_name)`

Comment: Make sure if you're using it in a method you're passing Request $request as a paramenter.

Comment: For Example: public function method1(Request $request){ ....}

Comment: Also make sure props_name is a string that you want to call. Usually it's the id.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure pass data from view to controller in form you must use method ="post"
Then you can access from controller using request method like..
For all passing data
$request->all() ;

And  specific field you can use 
$request->get('course_title') ;
like this 
Thank you